# нарисовать иконку средствами directX9

Tags: c++, directx

Делаю подобие диспетчера задач, в данный момент проблема в следующем:
Необходимо отобразить список процессов и возле каждого процесса нарисовать соответствующую ему иконку, так вот получить иконку процесса я нашел как:

- ExtractAssociatedIcon
- SHGetFileInfo
- IExtractIcon
- ExtractIconEx

Все функции по получению иконок из процессов возвращают HICON*. Как можно отрисовать это средствами directX9? Пожалуйста помогите разобраться или хотя бы подкиньте идей...

Comment: Если есть какие-то проблемы с прорисовкой HICON, то можно попробовать конвертнуть в тот тип, с которым проблем нет.

Comment: @alexolut - как например сконвертировать в jpg или хотя бы ico, как должен происходить процесс? Я должен загружать в ресурсы своего приложения или создавать файл? какими функциями пользоваться D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemoryEx? или что-то другое пожалуйста объясни.